# Can I search package by name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, package, jetbrains-ide

I like the feature in Android studio that looks for classes (Cmd + Shift + O). However, I would like to look for packages named "model" in the whole huge project. How can I do that?

Comment: You can basically search everything by pressing the shift key two times in windows whether it is a class file or layout file or may be package too. Just try using double shift once and it helps like hell

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android - Packages]

Top left hand side of android studio, click the drop down and navigate to packages

Comment: But I have a lot of build variants and modules in my project. Wanna just find them by name, don't expand everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with the answer provided by A. Nutley or if you want to search for any file present in your package or in your whole project, you can use the keyboard shortcut  `Ctrl + shift + N` in Windows or `Cmnd + shift + N` in Mac.

Here's an image for reference.
[image: File Search bar]

Comment: It gives me Languages window, not searching

Comment: Chech the Image. Isn't this what you are seeing??